# Get specific part of a URL value

Tags: php, wordpress

I used a code to bulk import the envato items, 
for example the envato items url is like this :

```
http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226
```

How to get only the part "2833226" of this URL with PHP?
I use wordpress and have used custom fields to insert envato item links
for example a custom field (afflink) with value :

```
http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226
```

and this code to call the custom field value in the theme

```
$afflink = get_post_meta($post->ID, "afflink", false);
```

How to get only the item number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for certain values in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036271/how-to-check-for-certain-values-in-url)

Answer (score 3):

Use explode to split using `/` caracter and then get the last element of array:

```
<?php

    $url='http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226';

    $y=explode('/',$url);

    $affiliateID = end($y);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you FaceOfJock thats worked! sorry my reputation dont allow me to vote up your comment

Comment: validate it as solution then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/\d+$/";
$input = "http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226";

preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);

//Your ID
$post_id = $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
value = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $url = 'http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226?r=1';
 $urlParts = parse_url($url);
 $path = $urlParts['path'];
 $pathParts = explode('/',$path);
 $item_id = end($pathParts);
```

The above code will make sure to avoid query string and read only Uri